# Need a bit of direction with NASA's Insights API for a Mars weather App

Tags: javascript, api

I'm looking for some help with [NASA's insight API](https://api.nasa.gov/assets/insight/InSight%20Weather%20API%20Documentation.pdf). I can see the object in my console, (for some context I'm a total newbie at coding) and I'm just trying to get the pressure data: PRE min, max, avg, and sol keys.

I don't really know what to do next, anyone that could point me in the right direction would be awesome, thanks.

So far I've got this. I have a key but just displaying the demo.

```
const BASE_URL = 'https://api.nasa.gov/insight_weather/?api_key=DEMO_KEY&feedtype=json&ver=1.0';


let weather = [];

const $weather = $('#weather');



init ();

function init() {
 getData();
}


function getData() {
$.ajax(BASE_URL)
    .then(function (data) {
        
        console.log(data);
         weather = data;
        render();
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}

function render () {
   // console.log(weather);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is your goal next? What are you trying to achieve without succeding? What have you tried? We can't code your whole app for you, we can only hellp you with the specific problems you find along the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this API.

```
https://mars.nasa.gov/rss/api/?feed=weather&category=insight_temperature&feedtype=json&ver=1.0
```

I got this from https://mars.nasa.gov/insight/weather/.

Answer (score 0):

Insight has unfortunately stopped working after 4 years: https://www.nasa.gov/press-release/nasa-retires-insight-mars-lander-mission-after-years-of-science